# How to use the methods made from a class

Tags: python

I want to use a method that I made within a class on a list of animals but I am unsure of how to do so.

I've tried calling the method on the list, but I guess because the method is within my class it can't identify it.

```
from src.ruminant import Ruminant
class Goat(Ruminant):

    def __init__(self, age):
        Ruminant.__init__(self, age)


    def make_sound(self):
        return Ruminant.make_sound(self) + " - baah"

#in another program vvv

animals = [Goat(2.0), Goat(2.1)]
```

This is just an example because I want to try to do some on my own, but I am unsure of how to make it output baah baah.  Any help would be much appreciated and if I haven't worded this whole question well I am happy to try to further explain.

Comment: `for animal in animals: animal.make_sound()` should work your variable is list so you need to iterate trough it to call your class function

Answer (score 7):

After you have the list:

```
animals = [Goat(2.0), Goat(2.1)]
```

Just do :

```
for animal in animals: 
    animal.make_sound()
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you understand and can explain what a *method* is, specifically the notion that a *method* is fundamentally part of a class. When you write this:

```
animal = Goat(2.0)
```

You create a Goat *object*, sometimes referred to as an *instance* the Goat *class*, and assign it to the name `animal`. Once you have an object, you can call the methods that are defined for it:

```
animal.make_sound()
```

In Python, the square brackets `[]` are used to define a special data structure called a list. When you type:

```
animals = [Goat(2.1), Goat(2.2)]
```

you are creating two separate goat instances, and storing them in a list. The list is assigned the name `animals`, and can be accessed using special syntax.

Items in a list have an index number, which can be used to access individual members. This is how you would access the first object in the list:

```
animals[0]
```

Note that most programming languages are *zero indexing* meaning they start at index `0`. So the second object in the list would be:

```
animals[1]
```

Just like before, we can call methods that are defined for items in the list:

```
animals[0].make_sound()
animals[1].make_sound()
```

Once you understand how that works, it makes sense to ask "what if I don't know how many animals there are in a list?" And in that case, you need to recognize that, for each animal in your list, you would be performing the same operation: calling `make_sound()`. If you wanted to call that method on a list with any number of animals, you could do it like this:

```
for animal in animals:
    animal.make_sound()
```